# #sinfonier BOLT - Adding a jarray object to output

Tags: java

If I make

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
[...]
this.addField("array", array);
```

it generates:

```
{..., "array":"[\"x\", \"y\"]" }
```

When it should be:

```
{..., "array": ["x", "y"] }
```

The sinfonier probably calls toString on the jarray object. I think it should create a full json and then call toString on the full json.

Is there any other way to do this?

(this is a sinfonier specific question, sorry, but no sinfonier tag available yet)

Answer (score 0):

So, I participate in sinfonier Hackathon on Campus Party Recife, if you need create a array you need create json objects before and add them in array, like this:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
...
List aryLst = new ArrayList();
aryLst.add("x");
aryLst.add("y");
JSONArray list = new JSONArray(aryLst);
```

Sinfonier use org.json package to manipulate json objects.

But if your bolt gets json from a truple and you save a value of a json in a field you can get this value directly from truple and save. Or you can use json fields normaly like a field in other bolt or drain.

Comment: does it make a difference creates a JSONArray with a constructor or using the put method? I dont think so, but I can try. The problem here is that when I add a JSONArray to an output (like this.addField("array", array);), sinfonier outputs it as string.

Comment: Why you need pass a Json as field? You really need pass a Json? Why not create a field to X and other to Y and process this information in  drain or other bolt? Please send a screenshot of your topology.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an array list and add it into a field to your current tuple/map it's necessary to make an ArrayList> instance.

Firts import com.google.gson libraries:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

Then add every item from your source array to new ArrayList instance:

```
JSONArray originalJsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> newArrayList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
if (originalJsonArray != null) {
    for (int i=0;i<originalJsonArray.length();i++){
        Map<String, Object> fieldValueItem = new Gson().fromJson(originalJsonArray.get(i).toString(), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
        newArrayList.add(fieldValueItem);
     }
}
```

Finally add your new array:

```
this.addField("newarraylist",newArrayList);
this.addField("newarraylistlength",newArrayList.length());
```